# Dataframe isin function Buffer was wrong number of dimensions error

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have a dataframe with customer info including first and last name (separate columns). I have an array of names and I want to separate the dataframe according to the names array. I load the csv file as so:

```
names = np.loadtxt("names.csv", delimiter=",", dtype=str)
```

I tried to use the isn.any function but got the buffer was wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2) error

```
df = df[df[['First Name','Last Name']].isin(names).any(axis=1)]
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Take the expression apart, and pay attention to the error traceback.  Check the dimensions of `names` and `df`.  Then is the `df` `isin` complaining, or the `any`.  While `names` is a `numpy` array, `df[...]` is a dataframe.

Comment: Welcome. In the spirit of [Ask], especially the [mre] part, please replace the csv reading part with a small dataframe, a mock-up if you like that would allows reproducing your problem.

Comment: I figured it out, i just had extra columns on the csv file resulting in extra dimensions essentially. I have since removed them. Seems to be working for now